# Hyper-V Switch between internet connections using default gateway

Tags: networking, router, internet, hyper-v

I have two router in my home network and both of them have different internet connection meaning I have two internet connection at my house with two separate routers. Below are the config of these routers:

**Primary Router**
`LAN Address`: **192.168.0.1**
`DHCP Enabled`: **Yes**
`DHCP IP Range`: **192.168.0.100** - **192.168.0.199**

**Secondary Router**
`LAN Address`: **192.168.0.2**
`DHCP Enabled`: **No**

I have connected Primary Router with Secondary Router via ethernet cable on LAN to LAN port. Now what I want to do is use internet from my Secondary Router when internet from Primary Router is down. To test this, I went into windows ethernet network adapter IPV4 settings and manually added IP address **192.168.0.102** which is reserved for my PC in Primary Router DHCP setting and entered default gateway as **192.168.0.2**.
After setting up above settings, I searched for my IP on google which is still showing IP from internet connection from my Primary Router

I do not understand why it is still going to Primary Router internet even though I specified gateway IP which is from Secondary Router. Maybe I am missing some steps here. Any help will be appreciated.

#EDIT
I tested this with another computer and it is working fine in other computer. Then I remember that I have Hyper-V enabled in my computer and I have created virtual switch on my computer's ethernet port from Hyper-V settings. Could this be the reason? If yes then is there any solution around it?

[image]

Comment: The setup seem ok, disconnect the primary router from the internet and check what happens then.

Comment: @Albin I disconnected internet ethernet cable from wan port from my primary router as you suggested and used second router LAN address as  gateway in windows network settings and with this, I cannot connect to internet.

Comment: Any IP Address in the 192.168.0.X subnet does not exist outside of your network.  If your device is assigned an IP Address in that subnet it means it's connected to an internal device that is acting as the DHCP server.  "I searched for my IP on google which is still showing IP from internet connection from my Primary Router" - This makes it sound like you are performing a Google search on an intranet IP Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. The whole setup is fine and it will work as intended. Unless if you have Hyper-V virtual external switch created in your system. In that case rather than setting up static IP and default gateway on physical ethernet adapter, set it up on Hyper-V virtual external switch adapter. After that I am able to switch between internet connections by changing default gateway.